question regarding the solution of a differential equation
I want to solve the question : $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{ln x}{xy}$, $y(1)=2$.
Using simple calculus, we have
$\int y dy = \int \frac{lnx}{x} dx$
$\frac{y^2}{2} = \int ln|x| d(ln|x|)$
and we reached the general solution $y^2 = (ln|x|)^2 +c$.
By the condition $y(1)=2$ ,we have $y^2 = (ln|x|)^2 +4$
Question: Should I take the positive sign or the negative sign of the solution $y$?

The positive one or you violate the initial condition. If $y(1)=-2$ you would take the negative root.

why is that so? is there a theorem for this or can you elaborate more?

i mean , if we consider the general case $y(t_0)= a$, if a is positive ,then should we only consider the positive sign?

Plenty of theory about when an initial value problem has a unique solution. The positive root solves your ivp, the negative root does not.

@Paul i thought very hard about your comment and i figured it out, thank you for your comment.
